# Script only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is driving me crazy...

I want my sign up form to slide from the right of the page when I click a button and then slide off when I click the same button again (sort of a toggle).

It works great the first time, but when I click the button a third time to show the form again, nothing happens... WHY?

Here's my head script:

```
function moveme() 
{
    var form_pos = document.getElementById('signup');
    if(form_pos.style.right <= 0)
    {
        $('#signup').animate({right:'100px', opacity:1},700);
    }
    else
    {  
        $('#signup').animate({right:'0px', opacity: 0},700);
    }
}
```

and I have this on the body:

```
<a id="action-top" onclick="moveme();" href="#" class="button yellow">GAME ON!</a>
<div id="signup">MY FORM </div>
```

And CSS:

```
#signup
{
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-300px;
    padding:30px;
    background:#eee;
    z-index:999;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging in developer tools?  Do you get a javascript error after the first click?

Comment: No erros in console..

Comment: Try logging the if statement in the `moveme()` function, specifically the `form_pos.style.right` var.  My guess is that the comparison statement isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById('signup')`, if you have jQuery installed? That's not an error, just a bad practice, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your if condition to this

```
if (form_pos.style.right == '0px' || form_pos.style.right == '')
```

here is the fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/26WBd/3/

Answer (score 5):

The default value of a `.style.*` property is taken from the style attribute, not the CSS cascade.

Since you aren't setting `right` there, the default value is `""`.

```
> "" <= 0
true
```

Since an empty string is less than or equal to zero, you set it to `"100px"`

Next time you test it:

```
> "100px" <= 0
false
```

So you set it to `"0px"`, and then:

```
> "0px" <= 0
false
```

You should be testing `parseInt(form_pos.style.right, 10)` instead and special casing the `NaN` value.

Comment: Using `parseInt($('#signup').css('right'), 10)` would also work and give `-300` initially instead of `NaN` because jQuery uses `computedStyle` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

**Using jQuery** much easier and cleaner way to achieve it.

```
$("#action-top").click(function(){
    var signupForm    = $("#signup");
    var formPosition  = parseInt(signupForm.css("right").replace("px",''));

    if(formPosition <= 0)
      signupForm.animate({right:'100px', opacity:1},700);
    else
      signupForm.animate({right:'0px', opacity: 0},700);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26WBd/9/

Answer (score -1):

(form_pos.style.right <= 0) is false second time around, therefore the animation is too small to be seen.

Try (form_pos.style.right <= 50)